# Entity Framework Distinct records from multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, distinct

I am trying to get distinct values by joining multiple tables. Can someone please tell me how to do the same in the below code?

Please see the sample code below:

```
var distinctValues = (from a in dataContext.A_Table
                      join b in dataContext.B_Table on a.EmpID equals b.EmpID
                      join c in dataContext.C_Table on b.SomeID equals c.ID
                      where a.IsActive == true
                            && a.ID == id
                      select new NewClass()
                                 {
                                    ID = c.ID,
                                    Name = c.Name
                                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: It's enough to add `Distinct()` just before `ToList()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this should work without many changes, though i would have wrote it entirely in expressions:

```
var distinctValues = (from a in dataContext.A_Table
                      join b in dataContext.B_Table
                      on a.EmpID equals b.EmpID
                      join c in dataContext.C_Table
                      on b.SomeID equals c.ID
                      where a.IsActive == true
                      && a.ID == id
                      select new NewClass()
                      {
                          ID = c.ID,
                          Name = c.Name
                      }).ToList()
                      .GroupBy(x=>new {ID = x.ID,Name = x.Name})
                      .Select(x=>new {ID = x.Key.ID,Name = x.Key.Name});
```

Comment: I think the above code returns only the distinct Names but I need distinct objects of NewClass (i.e. with ID & Name columns). Can you please tell me how to return distinct ID & Name in the form of NewClass objects?

Comment: Then you should change Distinct with a GroupBy. Check my update.